# Unable to attribute transactions & revenue to channels in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

We are unable to attribute transactions & revenue to channels in GA4? We are using server side measurement protocol to push GA4 eCommerce data and having difficulty with traffic source attribution

We successfuly have transactions & revenue attributing to unnasigned but not to the correct channels